# what happens when we overwrite cv::Mat.data

Tags: c++, opencv

What will happen when we manually add an address of a buffer in `data` attributes of  a `cv::Mat` object, and later delete that buffer?

For example,

```
cv::Mat test;
test.data = (address of Buffer A);
```

what will happen to `test.data` when `Buffer A` is deleted?

Comment: Can you post code doing what you describe?

Comment: Why not use one of these two constructors? 'Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP); 
Mat (Size size, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP);' They will set the data pointer, along with the correct type and size. Read the documentation here http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html

```
int rows, cols, type; // you need initialize them
void* data = (address of Buffer A)
cv::Mat test = cv::Mat(rows, cols, type, data); // according to documentation, test does not own data
cv::Mat copy = test.clone() // copy copies is a deep copy of test
```

So since test does not own Buffer A, once it's delete, if you access test.data, it's UB.
However, since copy is a deep copy, you can access copy.data